# How do I use an array of named indices (keys) to set a value in a nested hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given any nested hash, for example:

```
{ canada: 
  { ontario: 
    { ottawa: :me}, 
    manitoba: 
    { winnipeg: nil}}, 
  united_states: 
  { district_of_coloumbia: 
    { washington: nil}}}
```

how can I use any array of keys `[:canada, :ontario, :ottawa]`  or `[:united_states, :district_of_columbia, :washington]` to get or set a value.

Basically, my problem is how do I change `[:canada, :ontario, :ottawa]` into a getter or setter of the format `hash[:canada][:ontario][:ottawa]` when I don't know the length of the array of keys.

so I can do something like:

```
hash[:canada][:ontario][:ottawa] = nil
hash[:canada][:manitoba][:winnipeg] = :me
```

I made a getter using recursion:

```
def reindex(h, index_array)
  i = index_array.shift
  result = index_array.empty? ? h[i] : reindex(h[i], index_array)
  result
end
```

But I feel like I'm over thinking this and there should be a simpler way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'when I don't know the length of the array of keys.' , I dont see any array. I only see hashes!

Comment: @ArthurNeves `[:canada, :ontario, :ottawa]` is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler approach(in my opinion) is to access elements successively with `:[]`:

```
keys = [:canada, :ontario, :ottawa]
hash = { canada: { ontario: { ottawa: :me}, manitoba: { winnipeg: nil} }, united_states: { district_of_coloumbia: { washington: nil } } }

# get
p keys.inject(hash) { |h, k| h.public_send(:[], k) }
#=> :me

# set
last = keys[0..-2].inject(hash) { |h, k| h.public_send(:[], k) }
last.public_send(:[]=, keys[-1], 'other')
p hash #=> {:canada=>{:ontario=>{:ottawa=>"other"}, :manitoba=>{:winnipeg=>nil}}, :united_states=>{:district_of_coloumbia=>{:washington=>nil}}}
```

Wrapped in methods:

```
def get_by_keys(hash, keys)
  keys.inject(hash) { |h, k| h.public_send(:[], k) }
end

def set_by_keys(hash, keys, v)
  last = keys[0..-2].inject(hash) { |h, k| h.public_send(:[], k) }
  last.public_send(:[]=, keys[-1], v)
  hash
end

keys = [:canada, :ontario, :ottawa]
hash = { canada: { ontario: { ottawa: :me}, manitoba: { winnipeg: nil} }, united_states: { district_of_coloumbia: { washington: nil } } }

p get_by_keys(hash, keys) #=> :me
p set_by_keys(hash, keys, 'other') #=> {:canada=>{:ontario=>{:ottawa=>"other"}, :manitoba=>{:winnipeg=>nil}}, :united_states=>{:district_of_coloumbia=>{:washington=>nil}}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be something like `.public_send(:[], :key)` I just had no idea what to Google to find it.

Comment: @PareidoliaX check my edit for setter and update your code. I optimized it to separately handle last iteration. It improves performance(no need to check for last element each iteration) + correctly resolves the case with duplicated keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Hash
  def deep_fetch(*path)
    path.reduce(self) do |mem, key|
      mem[key] if mem
    end
  end

  def deep_assign(*path, val)
    key = path.shift

    if path.empty?
      self[key] = val
    else
      if self[key].is_a?(Hash)
        self[key].deep_assign(*path, val)
      else
        self[key] = path.reverse.inject(val) { |a, n| {n => a} }
      end
    end

    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
countries = {:canada=>{:ontario=>{:ottawa=>:me}, :manitoba=>{:winnipeg=>nil}}, :united_states=>{:district_of_coloumbia=>{:washington=>nil}}}
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
hash.merge!(countries)

hash[:canada][:ontario][:ottawa] = nil
hash[:canada][:manitoba][:winnipeg] = :me

hash
=> {:canada=>{:ontario=>{:ottawa=>nil}, :manitoba=>{:winnipeg=>:me}}, :united_states=>{:district_of_coloumbia=>{:washington=>nil}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think recursion is your best option. I wouldn't consider it "overthinking" I'd do:

```
def getter(hash, array)
  return hash[array[0]] if array.count == 1
  getter(hash[array[0]], array[1..-1], item)
end

def setter(hash, array, item)
  return hash[array[0]] = item if array.count == 1
  setter(hash[array[0]], array[1..-1], item)
end
```

Comment: Not working for me. seems to break after the first recursion. `[5] pry(main)> getter(@hash1, @loc)
NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for :canada:Symbol
from super_hash.rb:29:in `getter'
[6] pry(main)> setter(@hash1, @loc, :you)
NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for :ontario:Symbol
from super_hash.rb:34:in `setter'`

Comment: You are right, I will fix the error. The problem is `array.shift`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recursion is an option. Here's how it could be implemented.

**Code**

```
def get(hash, arr)
  case arr.size
  when 1 then hash[arr.first]
  else get(hash[arr.first], arr[1..-1])
  end
end

def set(hash, arr, val)
  case arr.size
  when 1 then hash[arr.first] = val 
  else set(hash[arr.first], arr[1..-1], val)
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
hash = {
  canada: {
    ontario: 
      { ottawa: :me }, 
    manitoba: 
      { winnipeg: nil }
  }, 
  united_states: {
    district_of_columbia: 
      { washington: nil }
  }
}

arr_can = [:canada, :ontario, :ottawa]
arr_us  = [:united_states, :district_of_columbia, :washington]

get(hash, arr_can) #=> :me
get(hash, arr_us)  #=> nil

set(hash, arr_can, 'cat')
set(hash, arr_us,  'dog')

hash
  # => {:canada=>{:ontario=> {:ottawa=>"cat"},
  #               :manitoba=>{:winnipeg=>nil}},
  #     :united_states=>
  #              {:district_of_columbia=>{:washington=>"dog"}}
  #    }
```